# My hero image zooms in when I scale the browser width

Tags: html, css

I can't get my hero background image to stop zooming in when I scale the browser width. I want the image to look the same on a desktop/laptop as it does on mobile.  I have tried to use object-fit but it doesn't seem to be making any difference, I have also tried setting static width and heights.
can anyone help or point me in the right direction.

Html

```
 <body>
    <header id="showcase" class="grid">
        <div class="bg-image"></div>


    </header>


    </body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

#showcase {
    min-height: 450px;
}

.bg-image {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(girlsmall.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;

}


/* small tablet styles */
@media screen and (min-width: 620px){


}

/* large tablets and laptops */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px){
    body{
        font-size: 18px;
    }


}

/* desktop styles */ 
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){

     body{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what `background-size:cover` does. It will make the image as wide as possible without stretching it, cropping where needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#cover

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want ? i didn't set the picture as a background, but just used the `z-index` property.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            html, body
            {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            #a
            {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                z-index: -1;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="a" src="girlsmall.jpg" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```